# How to insert a new item in a listbox and then setfocus on the listbox new item on a button click event in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox which populated from using a datatable. I have a Add button in my page. On clicking the add button I want to insert a blank row in the listbox. This can be done easily by

```
ListBox_Admin.Items.Add("");
```

after this is done I want to select this item as in setfocus on this item.How do I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
listBox1.Items.Add("");
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListBox_Admin.Items.Add(item);
ListBox_Admin.SeletedItem = item;
```

Answer (score -2):

Or:

```
ListBox_Admin.SelectedValue = "";
```